# Mongoose Model find() returns empty array with node js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

When i am trying to fetch data from database using mongoose model i always getting empty array.
I am using nodejs with express to fetch data from mongodb using mongoose by using find() function.

But when i am using `db.collectionname.find({});` in mongoshell than i am getting all the values.

Below is my model code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('debug', true);
var schema = mongoose.Schema;

var countriesSchema = new schema({
    id : {
        type : Number,
        required : true
    },
    code : {
        type : String,
        required :true
    },
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    phonecode : {
        type : Number,
        required : true
    }
});

var Countries = module.exports = mongoose.model('Countries', countriesSchema);

module.exports.getCountries = function(callback){
    Countries.find({}, callback);
}
```

Below is my routing file code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var configMain = require('./../config/main');
var https = require('https');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var countriesModel = require('./../database/models/countries.model');
var statesModel = require('./../database/models/states.model');
var citiesModel = require('./../database/models/cities.model');


router.get('/get-country-city-state',function(req, res, next){
    var response = {};
    if(req.query.type == "getCities"){
        citiesModel.getCities(req.query.stateId, function(err, cities){
            sendResponse(err, cities);
        });
    }else if(req.query.type == "getStates"){
        statesModel.getStates(req.query.countryId, function(err, states){
            sendResponse(err, states);
        });
    }else if(req.query.type == "getCountries"){
        countriesModel.getCountries(function(err, countries){
            sendResponse(err, countries);
        });
    }else{
        sendResponse(err, null);
    }
    //res.send($response);
});

function sendResponse(err, data){
    if(err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    console.log(data);return;
    /*for(var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++){

    }
    response = {'success' : 1, 'result' : dataResult};*/
}

module.exports = router;
```

In my database i have data like:

```
  {
       "_id": ObjectId("58d018733b3161574df5ebe1"),
       "id": 1,
       "code": "AF",
       "name": "Afghanistan",
       "phonecode": 93
   }
```

In my `console.log(data)` i am getting empty array when i am fetching all the countries.

Comment: Everything seems fine in your code. Are you sure that you are connected to the same database you're querying against from the mongoshell?

Comment: Yes it is connected to same database

Comment: Any update on this? I'm running into mostly the same exact issue.  I had successfully used another DB & Collection prior to changing to a different DB.  I changed the connected DB and have tested fetching the data in mongo client with success, but when attempting to get the data through my node app, it's returning an empty array. When switching back to the DB that worked for me, I started to wonder if it had anything to do with the _v:0 property that was created on my documents within the 'working' DB.